# Remove unicode characters from Cheerio.js content

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode, cheerio

I’m using [cheeriojs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) to scrape content off a webpage, with the following HTML.

```
  <p>
     Although the PM's office could neither confirm nor deny this, the spokesperson, John Doe said the meeting took place on Sunday.
  <br>
  <br>
    “The outcome will be made public in due course,” John said in an SMS yesterday.
  <br>
  <br>
 </p>
```

I’m able to reach the content of interest, by class and id tags, as follows:

```
$('.top-stories .line.more').each(function(i, el){
    //Do something…

    let content =  $(this).next().html();
}
```

Once I’ve captured the content of interest, I “clean” it up using regular expressions, as below:

```
let cleanedContent = content.split(/<br>/).join(' \n ');
```

Inserting a newline where an empty tag `(<br>)` is matched. So far all is good, until I look at the cleaned content below:

```
Although the PM&apos;s office could neither confirm nor deny this, the spokesperson, Saima Shaanika said the meeting took place on Friday. 

&#x201C;The outcome will be made public in due course,&#x201D;
```

It appears that punctuation marks, and perhaps some other characters, are stored according to their unicode codes. I may be wrong on this, and would welcome some correction to this line of thought.

Assuming that they are stored as unicode codes, is there a module that I could pass the “cleanedContent” variable, through to convert the unicodes to human readable punctuation marks/characters?

Should this not be possible, is there a better implementation of [cheeriojs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) that would avoid this? I'm totally open to the notion that I'm not using [cherriojs](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) correctly, and would love some direction as to new approaches I could try instead.

One way I can think of, is writing a module containing several unicodes and their corresponding unicodes, then look for matches, and replace a matched code with the corresponding human readable character. I have some intuitive feeling that someone's already done this or something similar. I'd rather not try to reinvent the wheel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheerio uses htmlparser2 internally.

Because of this, you can **use htmlparser2's `decodeEntities` option** during the load of the HTML string, which allows you configure how HTML entities should be treated.

**Example:**

```
$ = cheerio.load('<ul id="fruits">...</ul>', {
    decodeEntities: false
});
```

**Relevant docs:**

- [Cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#loading)
- [htmlparser2](https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2/wiki/Parser-options#option-decodeentities)

Comment: Thanks, this was quite helpful. I've managed to solve my problem.